# access objective-c exception in finally block

Tags: objective-c, exception

Given the following situation:

```
@try {
    @try {
        // raises an exception :)
        [receiver raisingFirstException];
    } @finally {
        // raises another exception :)
        [otherReceiver raisingFinalException];
    }
} @catch (id e) {
    printf("exception: %s\n", [[e stringValue] cString]);
}
```

Is there any way to either get the first exception within the
`@finally` block or to get both exceptions within the `@catch` block?

I have code where the `@finally` block does some checks which may raise an
exception but I don't want to loose the original exception (the root cause).

If there was no original exception but the checks fail I want the
exception they throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to assign the exception to a variable that is accessible from the rest of your block.

```
NSException *ex;
@try {
    @try {
        [someObject methodWhichCouldThrowException];
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
        ex = e;
    } @finally {
        [anotherObject methodWhichCouldThrowADifferentException];
    }
} @catch (NSException *e) {
    // From here you can access both the exception thrown by 'someObject'
    // as well as the exception thrown by 'anotherObject'.
}
```

Comment: Seems I have simplified my example too much. The first exception is thrown by a method somewhere else in the program.
I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: But can't you still do what you want by changing your 'finally' block to a 'catch' block and set the exception to a local variable there? I'll edit my response.

Comment: Okay, that may be an option. But the code won't be as simple as it is now :(.

Comment: Yeah, nested exception code is never pretty. But there's really no other way to do this. You have to put in lots of 'catch' blocks and maintain references to any exceptions you might need later.

Comment: Before the objective-c exceptions exists I used my own setjmp/longjmp implementation with a set of macros. While the macros were nearly mysterious I had access to the eventually occurred exception in the finally block :).